# Ask a gentile to do labor for himself?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles

I understand that we are (generally) not allowed to ask a gentile to do *m'lacha* for a Jew on *Shabas*. What about asking him to do *m'lacha* that we do *not* think will benefit a Jew?

(I'm thinking for example of telling a driver — let's say as he's leaving the Jewish neighborhood — to turn on his headlights, but my question is more general.)

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83577

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed to tell a nonjew to do a m'lacha for himself. Ramma siman 307 siff 21.

The Mishna Berurah #73 explains that since the item never belonged to a Jew, and the action being done is solely to benefit the nonjew, there was never a g'zeira of amira li'eino Yehudi.